# DataGrid - event after all columns have been created?

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

It seems I'm trying to do something simple, and I've got this weird feeling I'm using some really strange methods to achieve this.

I've got a couple of Silverlight `DataGrid` objects with a lot of custom-generated columns. These columns are generated during one of the `AutogenerateColumn` events. After all the columns have been generated and displayed, I want to synchronize their width and order (in other words: I'm creating a few "linked" grids which display different data but in a very similar manner).

The problem I'm facing? DataGrid doesn't seem to have an event that gets fired after all the data has been loaded and the columns have been drawn.

For the time being I'm using the `LayoutUpdated` event and check if the column count is what it should be. This works, but I can't shake the feeling that this is an ugly workaround.

Is there any better way to do things as soon as all the columns have been created by the DataGrid?

Comment: What about [DataGrid.Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.95).aspx)?

Comment: `DataGrid.Loaded` occurs only when the object is first loaded, is it not? When I refresh or change the data, I'd like to call the event again (as I will need to re-synch all the grids).

Comment: Ah, yeah..From reading the documentation, it seems like LayoutUpdated is your best option at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using LayoutUpdate... sad, but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do a manual edit of all the columns, you could just call a method after you assign the itemSource, since the updating of columns occurs after you set it.

Comment: As I've written in the question, the columns are created on one of the `AutoGeneratingColumn` events. As such, they aren't visible right after the `ItemSource` is assigned.

Comment: So you assign the `ItemsSource`... When its assigned you've registered for the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event to add additional columns? Events will block till all handlers are processed... So you should be okay.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. The `AutoGeneratingColumn` event is registered before the `ItemSource` is assigned. It has to be, otherwise I won't be able to generate those extra columns (unless I do it in a completely different moment, and scrap the `AutoGeneratingColumn` altogether). If I follow how the code works, then the event gets fired after `ItemSource` has been assigned AND the current method has finished.

Comment: I mean... You register for the event. After that you set the ItemsSource. During every autogenerated column the AutoGeneratingColumn gets fired. You then add another column of some sort. Eventually you want to resize all columns. During the set of the ItemsSource, the events fired are blocking. So your code wont continue to the next entry before this is completed. Post-processing (resizing) can be done right after the setting of the ItemsSource